# Proof by Induction - Am I doing this correctly?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, induction

> For all n that is a natural number where **n ≥ 4, n! > n^2**

We wish to prove by induction.
Let us call (n! > n^2) p(n).

**Base Case**: We will test out p(4).

4! = 24

$4^2 = 12.$ As 24 > 12, p(4) is proven.

**Induction Hypothesis and Conclusion:**

Assume $n! > n^2$ for all $n ≥ 4$

We wish to prove p (k+1). That is, $((n+1)! > (n+1)^2)$

$(n+1)! ≥ n!(n+1) > n^2(n+1)$ using the Induction Hypothesis

$n^2(n+1) ≥ (n+1)^2$ occurs when $n^2 ≥ (n+1)$

$ n^2 ≥ (n+1) $

$ n ≥ 1 + 1/n $

As n ≥ 4, this is true. There for, we have shown p(n+1) and proved the original statement.

Comment: Um... $4^2 = 16$

Answer (score 1):

There is a small problem: $4^2=16$ (not $12$).

And there is a big problem, which is when you write “Assume $n! > n^2$ for all $n ≥ 4$”. If you assume that, then you will be assuming the very thing that you wish to prove. What you should do is to take *some* $n\in\mathbb N$, to assume that the inequality $n! > n^2$ holds for *that* $n$ and to prove that then $(n+1)!>(n+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Seems good to me but for some minor mistakes:

Assume $n! \gt n^2$ for **some** $n$, not for **all**. With p(4), you have shown the statement only for one value.

You want to write $(n + 1)$ instead of ($n = 1$) in the second to last line and you can omit the last line in my opinion, since this inequality is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic and plan is absolutely correct but your execution has some bugs.

First off there is the silly bit that $4^2 = 16\ne 122$.... Oh, well.  That's trivial.

Then there is the the "Assume $n! \ge n^2$ for all $n\ge 4$".  That's actually what you want to prove.  In the induction step you want to assume $n! \ge n^2$ for *one* value of $n \ge 4$.

I see a lot of proofs that use "Assume this is true for $n =k$ for some value of $k \ge 4$".  There is an advantage to this in that it doesn't confuse the $n$ representing *any* value as it does in the statement and $n$ being a *specific* value as it does in the induction step.

$n^2 \ge (n=1)$.   I actually was not able to read this and honestly did not know what you meant. I finally realised it was a typo and you mean $n^2 \ge (n+1)$

The lines:

1 $n^2(n+1) \ge (n+1)^2$ whenever $n^2 \ge (n+1)$

2 $n^2 \ge (n+1)$

3 $n \ge 1 + \frac 1n$

It isn't clear what the logic behind this is supposed to say.  It looks like you are saying $n^2 \ge (n+1)$ as a fact and we don't know why you can say that.  And it looks like your conclusion is $n \ge 1 + \frac 1n$. And we don't know why we care about that.

You should somehow say "$n^2 \ge (n+1) \iff n \ge 1 + \frac 1n$; and that is our case because $n \ge 4$".  You could also add a line about *why* $n \ge 4$ means $n > 1 + \frac 1n$, but that's not a deal breaker.  ($1 + \frac 1n < 2$ so $n> 1+ \frac 1n$ will be true for all $n \ge 2$.)

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected the errors! I said $n2≥(n+1) $ because I thought that after using the IH, I didn't know how I can get the $n^2(n+1)$ to look more like $(n+1)^2$ 



I thought then by manipulating both sides of the inequality, I could get closer to the inequality I wanted to prove, and by squaring both sides, I got closer to it. By showing that $n≥1+1/n$, doesn't it show it works for n is greater to the very most 2, and therefor it will work for n ≥ 4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can make it slightly simpler by noting that

$$n!>n^2\iff (n-1)!>n.$$

Then,

$$n!=n(n-1)!>n^2>n+1$$

because $n^2-n=n(n-1)>1$ for $n>1$.